# Что за параметр msg?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Что за параметр msg, при отправке такого запроса на сервер, что получит функция, которая является обработчиком события success?

```
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Это ответ от сервера на ваш запрос, подробнее в [английских доках](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1) [или русских доках.](http://jquery-docs.ru/ajax/jquery-ajax/)    
Вкратце: что сервер вам пошлет, то и будет, а браузер попытается это распознать в соответствии с опцией dataType запроса и MIME-типом ответа

Comment: а как передать с сервера что-нибудь??
echo ?или как?

Comment: Ну а как вы отвечаете клиенту на не-ajax запрос? Так же отвечайте и на ajax запрос. Просто страничка не будет обновляться, а ответ будет обрабатываться скриптом.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить документации [[en](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)][[rus](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)], то функция, присвоенная ключу, success принимает целых три параметра и что это за параметры описано по ссылкам.